# Reconfigure the registry for new Oracle installation

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I have the following oracle homes installed on my Windows machine

- Oracle Developer Suite
- Oracle Discoverer
- Oracle 10G Client

I installed Oracle 10G database manually by following the following steps

- Created the necessary directories
- Setup pfile
- Created a new database (using the "create database" command)
- Setup listener

I am now running the admin scripts (catalog, standard, catproc etc).

The problem I have is I can connect to the database using sqlplus / as sysdba but I can't startup the listener. The problem I think is that the registry is showing that the Oracle 10G database is not the default home for Oracle. The registry is showing that Discoverer is the default home.

How do I change the registry so that the 10G database is the default home? Presumably these are set if you install using `dbca` or some other automated process?

The environment variables are already set to point to the 10G database.  When installing manually how do I setup the registry to update the Oracle homes?

Comment: Have you set up listener.ora? please provide the output of the following commands: - lsnrctl status - lsnrctl services - lsnrctl start

Comment: What behavior/error do you get when you try to start the listener?